# How to create and publish git repositoty from VS 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, github

I am trying to create new repository using visualstudio 2013 and also publish it through VS. But im getting error which doesn’t provide enough information
Here are the steps I followed:
1. Install git tools for VS.
2. Created local repository "MyRepo" using visual studio.
3. Created console app and added to local git repository.
4. Made some changes to the code.
5. Click Commit.
6. Click on sync.
7. Now I see publish option as expected, I enter remote URL https://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepo
Note: "MyRepo" does not exists in GitHub, so im expecting it will create one
8. Click on publish, Enter my credentials for GitHub
9. I get error

```
"An error occurred. Detailed message: Response status code does not indicate  success: 404 (Not Found)."
```

I thought I may have entered invalid credentials which I did not so now I am trying to re-publish the master branch again
1. Click on branches.
2. Right click on master branch from the unpublished branch and select publish.
3. At this time I did not get any option to enter remote URL.
4. Entered my credentials for GitHub.
5. I get error

```
   "An error occurred. Detailed message: Response status code does not indicate  success: 404 (Not Found)."
```

Any help on the error?